# Convert C program into assembly?

Tags: c, assembly

how exactly do I convert this C program into assembly code?`

```
  void main(){
    for(i=100;i<2000;i++)
{

    While(PORTA==12)
    {
    PORTB++;
    PORTC=i%200;
    if(PORTB==77)
    Break;
    }
    }

    }
```

Comment: Run it through a compiler and enable assembly listing

Comment: for `gcc` that would be the `-S` option

Comment: Use the `-S` option of your favourite C compiler.

Comment: Use this https://godbolt.org/

Comment: Isn't it kind of redundant to try and convert invalid `C` to any asm language?

Comment: Is this MPLAB C?

Answer (score -1):

If you want the machine code, use a debugger like OllyDbg. Try disassembling your program.